# Name Initial State for freezing RNN Model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to name the initial state in my RNN model so I can call it from my .pb file. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve the issue?

Steps I have taken:
(1) Train Model
(2) Save model
(3) Freeze model >> (.pb)

I am now trying to name my state nodes so I can use them during inference:
(1) I have named my input and output nodes
(2) I have named my final_state node
**(3) I have not been able to name my Initial_state node**

Code to name Initial_state node:
initial_state = tf.identity(cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.int32),name="initial_state")

Error I am getting when trying to save my model:
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.

RNN Model Code:

```
def build_graph(
    cell_type = None,
    state_size = state_size,
    num_classes = num_classes,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    num_steps = num_steps,
    build_with_dropout = False,
    learning_rate = learning_rate):

    # clean up any residual Tensorflow objects
    reset_graph()

    # data placeholders
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name='x')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name='y')

    # dropout placeholder
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')

    # embeddings are more efficient than one hot encoding
    # create a lookup table to your inputs that can run in parallel
    embeddings = tf.get_variable('embedding_matrix', [num_classes, state_size])
    rnn_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, x)

    # pick cell type
    if cell_type == 'GRU':
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(state_size)
    elif cell_type == 'LSTM':
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
    elif cell_type == 'LN_LSTM':
        cell = LayerNormalizedLSTMCell(state_size)
    else:
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(state_size)

    # add dropout    
    if build_with_dropout:
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, input_keep_prob=keep_prob)

    # initialize state    
    init_state = tf.identity(cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.int32),name="init_state")

    # dynamic_rnn
    rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)

    #with tf.control_dependencies([init_state.assign(states)]):
    #    rnn_outputs = tf.identity(rnn_outputs)

    # These are there simply to give the nodes a name. I.e. they take a node, add another node to it 
    # (which doesn't do much, just identity transform), but crucially, that node can have a name, which 
    # will be saved in the frozen graph can later be accessed in C++. (Note, tf.identity also merges 
    # multiple tensors together, but that's another detail).
    final_state = tf.identity(states,name="final_state")

    with tf.variable_scope('softmax'):
        W = tf.get_variable('W', [state_size, num_classes])
        b = tf.get_variable('b', [num_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

    # reshape to get last output
    rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, state_size])
    y_reshaped = tf.reshape(y, [-1])

    logits = tf.matmul(rnn_outputs, W) + b
    predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

    # minimize the mean squared errors.
    total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y_reshaped))

    # pick optimizer
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(total_loss)

    return dict(
        x = x,
        y = y,
        keep_prob = keep_prob,
        init_state = init_state,
        final_state = final_state,
        total_loss = total_loss,
        train_step = train_step,
        preds = predictions,
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference code like this, 
https://github.com/BrotherJing/RNN_tabletennis

```
        initial_state_c = tf.get_collection("initial_state_c")
        initial_state_h = tf.get_collection("initial_state_h")
        initial_state = []
        for i in range(len(initial_state_c)):
            initial_state.append((initial_state_c[i], initial_state_h[i]))
```